Excel Combo Stacked Graph not refreshing correctly
I've noticed a weird behavior on a report dashboard, I thought it was just happening on the dashboard but I replicated the issue by creating a new Excel file for testing. I've created a combo graph using stacked on both bars to see the difference between 2 series ( The data will be percentages).
The formulas are:
B4 = A4/A5
B5 = B2 - B4
Now, the Graph is using those 2 values as series for the graph but is not displaying the data correctly. Please see below picture

The weird thing is that if I delete the formula from B4 and I enter manually the value 0.833333 the graph will display the data correctly. Please see below picture

I'm a bit lost here because if I leave the formula and change the cell A4 to a different value, for example 14 it works ( All numbers from 1 to 14 will display correctly but when A4 is either  15,16 or 17 the graph does not display the data correctly unless I manually input the decimal value). For a greater value on Series 1 ( blue bar) the orange bar should be smaller.
The below is incorrect


Look at the legend on your X-Axis and make sure it is set to zero all the time

Thanks, it was setup to 0.5 on my excel test workbook

To set axis minimum value manually do the following:

Right click on the x axis
Select format axis...
In the Axis Options table click Minimum to Fixed and type in the box to the right 0
Click on Close

You will get the proportional measurement on the graph.

Thanks, I've reviewed the production excel workbook and it was on 0.75 , it is fixed now
